# Should we have a tag for Islamic-oriented investment questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

We get sporadic questions from Islamic users that have very specific [investing restrictions](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/07/islamic_investments.asp), because of their faith.

Those are good questions, and I welcome them into the site. I think a tag for these questions would be a good thing, to bind them together.

Maybe [islamic-investment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-investment)  or [islamic-banking](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-banking), something in between.

Possible candidate questions for this tag (not exhaustive):

- [How to save money if one needs it in 3-4 years?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/74250/27572)
- [Islamic Banks and Personal Lending](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/13026/27572)
- [What are the alternatives to compound interest for a Muslim?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/72218/what-are-the-alternatives-to-compound-interest-for-a-muslim/72227#72227)
- [The difference between Islamic Banks and Western Banks](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/12972/27572)
- [How do Islamic Banking give loans for housing purposes?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/15094/27572)

A country tag may not be recommended in this case, because Islam is present in almost all countries.

Comment: Related: [Are questions about personal finance from a religious framework on-topic?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/q/2384/10997)

Comment: BTW, implementing this doesn't require moderator intervention, except for making any necessary synonyms.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam everything can benefit from a little community discussion. I think i'll go with Joe's answer, it has insider point of view.

Comment: @Mindwin - absolutely, this thread was important to have. Just didn't want you to think you had to wait for a moderator to conclude it. Let me know if I should make the synonyms.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I'll tag the sample questions, and create the tag wiki. Then you can make the synonyms as per Joe's answer.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I tagged the questions, but i cannot make the tag wiki. [waves fist] those perms...

Comment: @Mindwin OK, let me know what the tag wiki should be too (perhaps post an answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least for investing, the word "Sharia" would be most appropriate - Sharia being the name for the set of laws in Islam that apply. This is very consistently used in my experience with regard to [investments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia_investments);  [banking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_banking_and_finance) it doesn't seem to be as regular, but it is still the proper term ("Shariah compliant finance").

I also think that, while for non-Islamic folks "Islam" would be the word we expect, for those who follow that faith "Sharia" (or "Shariah") would be more commonly understood.

As such, I'd suggest:

[sharia-compliant-financing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia-compliant-financing)

with predefined synonyms

[shariah-compliant-financing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shariah-compliant-financing)
[sharia-banking](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia-banking)
[shariah-banking](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shariah-banking)
[islamic-banking](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-banking)
[islamic-finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-finance)
[islamic-investment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-investment)

all of which seem likely to come up to me (and if we have enough that do, the autocomplete will do the rest for us).

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a good idea, and I'd suggest [islamic-finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-finance), though either of the two suggestions in the question are fine too.

Answer (score 4):

The list of question is small. If we still want to have a tag; [islamic-banking](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-banking) is a better tag as it is well known word. It would be easier to think the term and tag.